# taking even number from user and giving exception error if number is odd

Tags: java, exception

I am a java student and I am writing a java program with exception handling. In this program, I am trying to write a program that gets 5 even number from user and if the user enter odd number then show an exception that the number is odd. I am using custom exception "oddexception" in this program.

Now let's talk about the issue. So I have an issue that this program isn't compiling. It show an error which is mentioned in the image below.

The answer to this question can be small and stupid for you but I am a beginner in java so this answer really matters for me. please help me.

Please help me to find a solution. The solution

```
import java.lang.Exception;
class oddexception extends Exception
{
    oddexception(String message, int a)
    {   
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("Invalid Number is/are "+a);
    }
}
class program4
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer n[] = new Integer[5];
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                n[i] = Integer.valueOf(args[i]);
                if(n[i]%2!=0)
                {
                    j++;
                    throw new oddexception("Number is odd "+n[i]);
                }
            }
            catch(oddexception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Caught my exception");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid numbers are : "+j);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message it quite clear that the constructor of your exception is expecting a String and an integer (`oddexception(String message, int a)`). Where as you just passing a String.

```
throw new oddexception("Number is odd "+n[i]); //results to String
```

So changing a bit of your code

```
  throw new oddexception("Number is odd " , n[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks bro! It worked. I was making this silly mistake. My teacher taught me about this. But being a beginner, it is natural i think.

Answer (score 4):

Your `oddexception` constructor has two arguments, so instead of

```
throw new oddexception("Number is odd "+n[i]);
```

you should write

```
throw new oddexception("Number is odd ",n[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wanted to ask to you follow [Java coding convention](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) and start your `ClassNames` with an uppercase character and then follow camel casing, by following these conventions your code will become more readable and understandable.

Now about your problem, you are accepting two arguments in your constructor `oddexception(String message, int a)`, one `String` and one `int`.

But while calling it you are passing only one argument `"Number is odd "+n[i]`, because `n[i]` will concatenate with the `String` and become a `String`.

So instead of `throw new oddexception("Number is odd "+n[i]);` you should write `throw new oddexception("Number is odd ", n[i]);`